# SharePoint 2013 - inherite/clone permissions for an aspx-site by list-settings

Tags: sharepoint, inheritance, permissions, user-permissions, propertybag

I'm facing the following problem:

I added a custom list setting, which is shown under the general settings of any list. The link in the general settings redirects to an aspx-Site where the admin can set some settings.

The normal users without the right permissions can't see the list-settings (which is correct) but they can open the aspx-site by calling the URL directly and change the values I store in the property-bag of the list.

The aspx-Site seems to inherite the permissions from the root, but I need it to have the exect same permissions I have for the list-setting page.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

I check the permissions in the code behind:

```
 if (!list.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ManageLists))
```

And I added this to the Elements.xml:

```
Rights="ManageLists"
```

Now the user isn't able to see the page unless he has the ManageList permission.

Maybe this will help somebody else later.

Thanks!